# Make my web application freeware

Tags: git, symfony, gitignore

I'd want my web application to be freeware and I'd upload it to Github, but I guess it can be a security hole if I put some kind of code, like DB configuration file (where there is my password), or any other. I'm working with Symfony2 and I don't know exactly what files I should "hide". Any suggestion?

Comment: https://github.com/Incenteev/ParameterHandler

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a new file called .gitignore at the root of your new project (e.g. next to the composer.json file) and paste the following into it. Files matching these patterns will be ignored by git:

```
/web/bundles/
/app/bootstrap*
/app/cache/*
/app/logs/*
/vendor/
/app/config/parameters.yml
```

Copy `app/config/parameters.yml` to `app/config/parameters.yml.dist`. The `parameters.yml` file is ignored by git (see above) so that machine-specific settings like database passwords aren't committed. By creating the `parameters.yml.dist` file, new users can quickly clone the project, copy this file to `parameters.yml`, customize it, and start using it.

The code of your application can be licenced under any open source licence. Choose one, which you like. Also edit your `composer.json` reflecting the choosen licence, a propper package name and so on.

Answer (score 0):

1. copy your `app/config/parameters.yml` to `app/config/parameters.yml.dist`
2. edit `app/config/parameters.yml.dist` and remove/edit your database configuration info
3. add `app/config/parameters.yml` to your `.gitignore`, so it will not be uploaded to GitHub
4. anything that you don't want to end up on Github should be added to `.gitignore`